# How often are the Pan-Hellenic Games held?

Tags: hellas-worlds-of-sun-and-stone

In the 2nd Edition of Hellas: Worlds of Sun and Stone, three different frequencies are given: annually (p. 24), every 5 years (p. 59), every 12 years (p. 21). It would be plausible that the interval was reduced from 12 years with the resumption of the Games in AE 2072, but is it 5 years or each year now?

Comment: Are you interested in answers from the PoV of pure canonicity, or from a more social-plausibility PoV?

Comment: I was hoping that there was a source book or errata or other official source that clarifies this, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an erratum about the frequency of games, I'm not aware of it. So my answer is forced to rely strictly on the analysis of indirect cues. It lead me to believe that the frequency was changed from 12 years to either 1 or 5.

First, why **the '12' number is likely obsolete by now:** it's the listed number before the century of no games, and were only held 12 times before that cessation; low frequency plus low total number of repetitions is a combination that makes a tradition less likely to last. Also, only holding games once per 12 years means there is a very small window of opportunity for heroes participating, what with the declining life expectancy in roughly the same Age. All of this means that when the talk of renewing the Games began (after decades of wars and of martial atheism), there were arguments for changing the timetable to a more frequent one. Finally, the timeline pages list what *was*, but presumably the culture and planet pages are meant to list what *is* (though they do conflict; see below). The one counterargument I can come up with is that the number 12 is symbolic of the Twelve Gods.

**Out of the two remaining, contemporary, possibilities, neither looks quite right.** The annual one can very weakly be associated with the Twelve Months representing Twelve Gods, but I haven't found any canonical, textual confirmation, so it's just a speculation. The quinquennial one can very weakly be supported by the analogy with historical (quadrennial) Olympiads - but 4 != 5, and surprisingly there *doesn't* seem to be any indication that the setting's Hellenic civilisation gives any special meaning to Olympiads (nor to five-year plans for that matter); saying that 5 is a typo in a place where a 4 was meant to be thoughtlessly typed seems like a ridiculous stretch. Conversely, from a sports perspective, both an annual and a qunquennial competition make sense, they just have different preparation cycles.

So I suppose if you want, you may, and in fact have to, **pick either one- or five-year** periods if you want to stick to canon, or **replace them with four-year ones** by analogy with the historical inspiration if you're fine with making adjustments.